# How to use EPCC's OpenMP Microbenchmark suite for my program

Tags: openmp, overhead, microbenchmark

I have implemented an application using OpenMP that I compiled with GCC on Ubuntu 16.04 for which I would like to calculate overheads in my application. (The binary file of my application is for e.g. `xyz.exe`.)

For that I'm trying to use *EPCC OpenMP micro-benchmark* suite. After `make`ing the suite, I tried to run one of the benchmarks called `syncbench` (`./syncbench`) on the terminal. But I would like to know as to how can I use the benchmark on my OpenMP implementation (`xyz.exe`). I tried to search the EPCC's official webpage for the suite (https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/research/computing/performance-characterisation-and-benchmarking/epcc-openmp-micro-benchmark-suite) and also the `README` available with the install code, but couldn't find how exactly can I do this.

If anyone has used this suite for their own implementation, please let me know how you have merged the benchmark with your implementation.

I'm new to parallel computing and benchmarking, so please excuse me if my query sounds trivial.

Comment: I changed the title, because it was confusing. I thought at first you have your own implementation of OpenMP.

Comment: @VladimirF: thanks for the changes. Also, I have my own implementation. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my query again.

Comment: No, your implenentation would be an implementation of the OpenMP itself, so you don't have your OpenMP implementation. That is the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a microbenchmark and a profiler. A microbenchmark (like EPCC) measures the performance of a specific set of small code fragments (in the case of the EPCC OpenMP benchmark, the performance of OpenMP constructs). A profiler measures the performance of any code and shows you where time is spent.

Therefore, to measure the behaviour of your code, you need a profiler (such as Intel Vtune, HPC toolkit, Tau, ...) not a microbenchmark.

[FWIW I work for Intel, but not directly on Vtune]

Comment: @JimCrownie: I'm already using the VTune Amplifier. But this profiler doesn't tell me how much overheads are introduced by OpenMP constructs (e.g. #pragma omp parallel). So, I just need to calculate the exact overhead time introduced by each construct in my C++ OpenMP code.

Comment: That is not trivial to do. You could look at time spent inside the OpenMP runtime (using whatever profiler you like), but that will show load-imbalance as overhead in the runtime (which it isn't). There are also costs from compiling for OpenMP (extra indirections when accessing shared data) that wont't be visible there.